# Shareit software for Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, software-recommendation, file-sharing

I have share-it software in windows O/S and android phone both. Using this software I can easily transfer my file over Wi-Fi.
Is there any software like share-it in Ubuntu 14.04, where I can transfer my file at android phone using wifi.

Answer (score 32):

### Using FTP

Here is another way to easily transfer files between your laptop and Android phone.

#### Prerequisite:

- Install [ES File Explorer (File Manager)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) on your Android

#### Procedure:

1. If both your Android and Ubuntu are connected to the same WiFi (same LAN), skip to step 3. Otherwise, create a WiFi hotspot on your Android:

   [image: settings -> "wireless & networks" -> more]

   [image: enable hotspot]
2. Connect your laptop to this WiFi network.

   [image: connect to hotspot]
3. Open **ES File Explorer** and open left-side menu.

   [image: open menu]
4. Go to **Network** -> **Remote Manager**

   [image: network -> remote manager]
5. Turn on the **FTP Server** and note down the **IP:port** address

   [image: turn on FTP]

   [image: get IP address and port]
6. Open Nautilus file explorer on Ubuntu. In **connect to URL**, type your phone's FTP server URL (from the previous step) and click on **Connect**

   [image: connect to FTP server in Nautilus]
7. If you need, You can set user name and password in ES File Explorer. By default, It will be public (anonymous).

   [image: access settings in ES]
8. In your PC, click on Connect. You can use the username and password that you set in ES File Explorer and connect as registered user.

   [image: log in to FTP server]
9. Now the internal memory of your phone is mounted. You can copy new files, remove files, do anything.

   [image: Phone storage mounted in Nautilus]

   If you wish to mount your SD card, you can set that in ES File Explorer settings.

Comment: You don't even need EsFile explorer. A much smaller and lighter tool EasyFTP can do that job

Comment: As of version 4, ES File Explorer is not worth installing. It's bloated and filled with ads.

Comment: Recently, Google Play Protect blocks installing ES Explorer due to collecting data to track you.

Answer (score 8):

#### Airdroid

Install the [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en), then to transfer files using wifi, you can use [web.airdroid.com](http://web.airdroid.com/), or the local address (in my case, [192.168.0.102:9000](http://192.168.0.102:9000/)). It doesn't need an active internet connection.

Comment: Airdroid needs your Wi-Fi and won't need an internet active connection.

Comment: Airdroid seems to have security issues.

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking for a solution to run SHAREit on Ubuntu without success, here's what I figured what is the most hassle-free approach, though it requires a Windows License of some sort:

1. Install Virtualbox on your Ubuntu box if you haven't already
2. Install a Windows from XP and up
3. Install SHAREit on Windows
4. Configure your local SHAREit folder on the Windows guest as a shared one with the host, if you need to access the files on your Ubuntu-box

Hope it helps!

Comment: Too many hassle this way imo.

Answer (score 3):

You can now send any files from your phone with ShareIt app to linux without any setup. ShareIt has got a feature "New Way of Connect to PC" which directly uses hotspot of the mobile to send file to PC.
To use it: Open ShareIt app -> Scroll Down to above option and follow the instructions.

Basically, at the receiving end, you need to connect to the host WiFi hotspot and navigate to a URL using a simple browser to download things. The ShareIt app serves the shared files at a local URL over it's network which can be downloaded via browser after connecting to hotspot.

Edit: This is not related to ShareIt but I find **Xender** app much more easy and fast to connect to PC and transfer files. Just navigate to *web.xender.com* scan QR code from its app and there! you are good to go!!

Answer (score 2):

If you  don't need internet then use  [super beam pro](http://superbe.am/for-pc/) for computer to phone transfer.

**Requirments**:

- Android devices must have PRO version of SuperBeam installed in order to work with PC app.
- Java 6 or later

Comment: This is not true. Airdroid doesn't need an active internet connection to share files. -1 for wrong information

Comment: @Anwar I removed it since it was irrelevant to this answer. I'll add more info to [rainu's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/672365/301745)

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked about shareit. But try KDEconnect, https://kdeconnect.kde.org/