# Exchanging files

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I want to use my laptop with my Android phone for exchanging files with each other without data cable and connecting to any external WiFi modem please let me know how to do it

Comment: Hi check the following link https://askubuntu.com/questions/633712/shareit-software-for-ubuntu

Comment: @moderator is this question is duplicate of the question in the link

Comment: I can see you are trying to accept all of the answers listed. Please select the one that works for you as "accepted". You may upvote them all if they were all helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, you can use ADB for this purpose...

1. Enable USB debugging in developer options on your phone
2. Install ADB on your computer
3. Plug in your phone
4. Run `adb tcpip 8084`
5. Unplug your phone
6. Run `adb connect 192.168.0.56:8084` (replace the IP address with your phone's address)
7. You can now transfer files.

   - To send a file to your phone:

     ```
     adb push /path/to/file/on/computer.txt /sdcard/folder/on/your/phone/
     ```
   - To receive a file from your phone:

     ```
     adb pull /sdcard/file/on/your/phone /folder/on/your/computer/
     ```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a hotspot on your laptop and use SFTP. To install the ssh server, just run

```
sudo apt install ssh
```

then you can SFTP by using the hostname which you can find with

```
hostname
```

All you need on your phone is an SFTP client.

Comment: By searching with the help of your suggestions i could find out ES File explorer which is helpful for exchanging files.

Comment: If it helped you, please mark it as the answer to help people in the future.

Comment: I have marked them.

Answer (score 0):

Install an [FTP Server](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=ftp%20server&c=apps&hl=de) app on your Phone and connect with your File browser or any FTP Client.

I use this one from F-Droid: [FTP Server (Free)](https://f-droid.org/packages/be.ppareit.swiftp_free/)

```
ftp://ip-address-of-your-phone/
```

Comment: OP said that they don't want to be connected to an external WiFi hotspot, which this requires.

Comment: This works with a simple Hotspot. I thought this is common knowledge and assumed OP knows how to create one ...